# Do questions about Jane's Naval Wargame fall on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There is this "board game" called Jane's Naval Wargame. It is an extremely large simulation wargame played by two teams in an extremely large area. Do questions about it fall on-topic here?

Comment: Related: [Are questions about 'Little Wars' on topic here?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/945/1644).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the Jane's Naval Wargame you're playing, it may meet the question guidelines detailed in the [help center](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I am aware of a "Jane's Naval Wargame" that includes using miniatures, made of paper tokens, based off the specifications detailed in Janes. It is played on a combination of nautical Charts and Topographic land maps, and follows a turn based structure, where *mission orders* are given, then processed.

The short coming I expect you might run into is a low population of individuals that use this site and are aware of the intricacies of the game. To my knowledge, it is mostly played by military offices and NCOs, in an academic or leadership development environment.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about the game and a brief google search didn't convince me that I'd found that right version of "Jane's Naval Wargame" so I'll drop back to our canned response, in our [faq](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

### How do we define Board Games?

- Be playable on or around a table
- Have objective rules of play and win conditions
- Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
- Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

When in doubt, just ask the question on the main site.  It might get closed as off-topic.  That's not a big deal.  Thanks!